# Need to write a function that returns all of the vowels in a word

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

I am new to learning python and am struggling to create a Function to return a string only of vowels from word no matter if its a blank string, string with no vowels, or string with all vowels.

This is what I wrote:

```
def vowels_only(word):
    word = "banana"
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    for letters in word:
        if letters == vowels:
            return letters
```

I expected to get: `"aaa"`

actual: `None`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `letters == vowels` checks whether `letters` _is equal_ to `vowels`. You are already using `letters in word` to look at the letters in the word... why did you do it differently for checking whether `letters` is in `vowels`?

Comment: `return` ends the function. You probably want to make sure you have the full string before returning it.

Comment: Why did you un-accept my answer? It produces comparable results as the answer you accepted, is explained better, is more efficient, and is far less code for the result. It just doesn't make sense. It's like I gave you a pair of Jordans and you traded them for Hoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check each letter against the values in vowels.

```py
def vowels_only(word):
    vowels = list('aeiouy')
    letters = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels and letter not in letters:
            letters.append(letter)
    return letters
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad to know that you have taken your first step in learning Python.

There are few mistakes in your code which it might run improperly.

1. `word` should not be inside `vowels_only()` function as the function needs to take word as function parameter.
2. `return` should not be used as function will stop running after returning a value.

Two methods can be used to solve this problem.

```
def vowels_only(word):
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    filtered = []
    for letters in word:
        if letters in vowels:
            filtered.append(letters)
    return "".join(filtered)

print(vowels_only("banana"))
```

In the above code, `"banana"` is taken as parameter and `filtered` is a list I declared to filter the vowels found from the word in Line 5.

```
def vowels_only(word):
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    for letters in word:
        if letters in vowels:
            yield letters

print(*vowels_only("banana"))
```

The second method, using `yield`. Return will stop the function from runnning. Use `yield` which is an alternative to it. However, `yield` will return generator object, hence pointer with `*` symbol is used to locate the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "banana"
b = "".join([t for t in a if t in "aeiouy"])
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` is already an `Iterable` type. There is no reason to convert it to a `list` or create any temporary `Iterable` types for processing.

> **Your goal is:**
>
> 1. iterate over each character in a word            (`for c in word`)
> 2. store characters that meet a specific condition. (`c in 'aeiouy'`)

You can work directly with the word using a generator. `join` is used to convert the generator result to a string.

```py
def vowels_only(word):
    return "".join(c for c in word if c in 'aeiouy')
```

---

An alternate method to use is `filter`. Each character of the word will be passed to the `lambda`. Every character that passes the `lambda` condition will be kept. `join` is used to convert the filter result to a string.

```
def vowels_only(word):
    return "".join(filter(lambda c: c in 'aeiouy', word))
```

---

A 3rd option is to use a regular expression, and replace the unwanted characters with an empty character. This method is over-engineered for your needs, but it's another example of the word being processed directly.

```
import re; from functools import partial

vowels_only = partial(re.compile(r'[^aeiouy]').sub, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for both your word and the vowels you want to find. It will be much easier to iterate over a list and then you can make a blank list to append all the vowels next time. Read the documentation about lists and try to post your proper code next time to get better help.

Comment: Both `list` and `str` are `Iterable`. The method you describe is unnecessary and bloated. There is nothing wrong with the OP's question or most of the help they received. Nothing you said is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).